# Freeware for extracting 7zip files?

Tags: macos

I've used [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) for this purpose, but it doesn't support extracting encrypted 7zip files. Can anyone suggest any other freeware for this?

BTW I'm using Mac OS X Leopard 10.5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Softonic has a nice [list](http://en.softonic.com/s/7zip%3amac) of 7Zip for Mac utilities. Some are freeware.

Comment: Downloaded 7zX from the list. Not the best software but works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some unofficial [p7zip packages for Mac OS X](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) exist, you can try them.

Comment: The link for page 'p7zip for Mac OS X' http://homepage.mac.com/krmathis/ returns with 404. Is it hosted somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using 7zX for unzipping 7zip archives. It works with passworded  and encrypted (with -mhe=on) archives. http://sixtyfive.xmghosting.com/products/7zx/